# automatically import maven projects from .bat file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have a .bat file that is creating the workspace for eclipse when executed on windows.

I want to import the maven projects when the .bat file is executed.(instead of manually adding the maven projects in eclipse)

So I added in the .bat file:

> call mvn -Declipse.workspace=eclipseWorkspace eclipse:add-maven-repo
>
> call eclipse -nosplash -application
>   org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -importAll
>   "svn://Repository..."

but got this error for the second call eclipse..:

> !MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Application "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild" could
>   not be found in the registry. The applications available are:
>   org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application,
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives.nativePackageExtractor,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher,
>   org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher,
>   org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench,
>   org.eclipse.ant.ui.antRunner,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication,
>   org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool,
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter,
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaIndexer.     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)

I could not find an example how to import maven project into eclipse through cmd. If someone can share some knowledge it will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Kire

Comment: out of curiosity, why the tag continuous-integration? what's the overall process?

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you import it headless?

If you want to provide a "taylormade" Eclipse incl. Workspace you can try Oomph or [Eclipse Profiles](http://profiles.yatta.de) -> http://profiles.yatta.de?download. Eclipse Profiles has SVN ...

Comment: Eclipse Profiles doesn't work for me, any idea how to import mavan/ant project in eclipse through cmd or .bat file